# Website reference and objects code errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I have a project which is a website working with SQL database. It is not my project but it is my website and I finally managed to get the source code from the coder. Long story....
I have loaded the project in VS2012 and managed to get the third party component Telerik and to sort out initial problems.
Now I am stuck with a series of errors related to something I do not understand how to solve. Please look at the picture:

[image]

I think it has something to do with the framework. It was developed in VS 2005 and framework 2. I am now in VS 2012 and framework 4 but I may be wrong. **Please can you give me a direction on how to solve these errors?**

```
Error   1   the name 'errlbl' does not exist in the actual contest. C:\Users\Pink\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Stadler_new\login.aspx.cs

Error   2   the name 'RadMenu1' does not exist in the actual contest.   C:\Users\Pink\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Stadler_new\projects.aspx.cs

Errore  15  the name 'Button2' does not exist in the actual contest.    C:\Users\Pink\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Stadler_new\Search.aspx.cs

and so on.....
```

Comment: Those errors relate to the project not being able to create those 3 controls, do they not?  Try creating a label with the name 'errlbl', a menu named 'RadMenu1' and a button named 'Button2' and then re-compile.

Comment: I will try. Let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Also, make sure that the references to those custom components is added into the project. Perhaps the reference is missing and could be why they cannot load.

Comment: @NicholasPost that is my concern. This is an obscure field for me. I would not know which assembly to add.

Comment: If you have the DLLs for those components, try right clicking your project in the solutions explorer, go to add reference, click browse, and select the file(s) you want to import.

Comment: @NicholasPost, thanks. That I know. What I do not know is to which dll they are belong to

Comment: The DLLs are listed in the images you posted above, Felice.  They are: `Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptManager`, `Telerik.Web.UI`, `Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenu` and `Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxPanel`.

Comment: The references are definitely all there.I think it has to do with the framework. If I had a new component "RadMenu" I get this message "the .net framework necessary to the assembly Telerik.Web.UI.dll or one of its dependencies is newer than the framework of the destination project. Should the reference be added in any case? ". This is a translation of the error made by me.